# Get ConstraintLayout in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

Good Daay,

I'd like to get a ConstraintLayout in a Fragment, however when debugging it priints 
this error
 `

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference**

on this line

**constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);**

So here are my activity used for the fragment and below the code of the fragment

fragment_activity:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.something.fragments.Fragment"
    android:id="@+id/this_fragment">

...



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here my code:

```
public class Fragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

View view;

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), R.style.Some_Theme_Name);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, null);

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.this_fragment);
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);


    return builder.create();
}

}
```

Help would be really appreciated

Comment: I recommend overriding `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()` and doing view related work there. `onViewCreated()` especially will provide you with a non-null view to use to findViewById.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however replacing getActivity()  with view helped here as I was already using view for the other findViewByIds, didn't see that however

Comment: Hi @Tester2389, can you accept my answer as correct if it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.this_fragment);
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, didn't use view anymore, as I've once had an weird issue with that thanks